# How to clean up string characters and ensure no unicode/ascii errors occur in Python

Tags: python, database, string, unicode, ascii

I have a database that contains non-ascii chars. And I need to clean the entire db. While doing it, I arrive at the following typical use-case :

```
kk =  "Hello there... ☃!"

kk.encode("ascii", "ignore")

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am cleaning the db following way, let me know if there is a better method.

```
def u_clean(s):
"""A strange attempt at cleaning up unicode"""

uni = ''
try:
    # try this first
    uni = str(s).decode('iso-8859-1')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    try:
        # try utf-8 next
        uni = str(s).decode('utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        # last resort method... one character at a time (ugh)
        if s and type(s) in (str, unicode):
            for c in s:
                try:
                    uni += unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', unicode(c))
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    uni += '-'

return uni.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

Answer (score -1):

You get an error because of the str(s) cast. first decode using utf8 (or whatever the incoming encoding is) and then encode into ascii.

```
>>> k = "Hello there... ☃!"
>>> k.decode('utf8')
u'Hello there... \u2603!'
>>> k.decode('utf8').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'Hello there... !'
```

The idea is the string has to be first interpreted correctly. so you decode to unicode using the original encoding, and then encode that unicode using ascii.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what is replayed over and over the SO. It's wrong: bad unicode characters causes encode/decode to raise exceptions (quite useless...).